# Conditional unique_together in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have following unique constraint in my model.

```
class Meta:
        unique_together = (('crop', 'order', 'sku'),)
```

But sku may be null in some cases and in that case this unique_together is not working as null is not equal to null.i am thinking to make a conditional unique_together like if sku is not null then (('crop', 'order', 'sku'),)  else (('crop', 'order'),).

Comment: Well since `null` is not equal to `null`, your constraint is already conditional.

Comment: But in case of null i don't allow to insert similar entry for crop and order.

Comment: what Django version do you use?

Comment: version =  3.0.6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can make use of [Django's constraint framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/), and add conditions to the [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint):

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['crop', 'order', 'sku'],
                name='unique_1'
            ),
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['crop', 'order'],
                condition=Q(sku=None),
                name='unique_2'
            )
        ]
```

Note that not every database per se supports this and thus will enforce this.

Comment: I have used the same way but reviewer is saying that it will through 500 error that is not good.

Comment: @ArvindKumar: if you do this through a `ModelForm`, it will normally check it and prevent ever inserting. If you insert it, then you should wrap it in a `try`-`except IntegrityError`, and return a sensical message.